# Всем привет! Подскажите способ отключения скролла страницы при открытом popup

Tags: javascript, css

В общем, я добавляю класс через скрипт и вроде скролл отключился, но после закрытия popup страница подъезжает к  своему началу. Я понимаю, что дело в position: fixed, но без него контент скроллится. Как можно все это обойти в моем случае?

```js
const openPopup = document.querySelector('.block');
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
const btnClose = document.querySelector('.popup-close');

function closePopup() {
  popup.classList.remove('popup-open');
  document.body.classList.remove('stop-scroll');
}

openPopup.addEventListener('click', () => {
  popup.classList.add('popup-open');
  document.body.classList.add('stop-scroll');
});

btnClose.addEventListener('click', () => {
  closePopup();

});
```

```css
.stop-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: -1268.8px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  &::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 20;
  }
}

.popup__inner {
  height: 100%;
  right: -100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 776px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 21;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.popup-open {
  right: 0;
  z-index: 25;
  opacity: 1;
  .popup__inner {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup__inner">
    //Popup content//
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отключения часто использовал `overflow: hidden` для `body`, но недавно обнаружил, что в некоторых **Safari** на **iOS** это не срабатывает, пришлось использовать такую конструкцию.

```
html.off-scroll,
html.off-scroll body {
  overflow: hidden;
  touch-action: none;
}
```

Ну и для активации\деактивации вешаем\удаляем класс `.off-scroll` на `document.querySelector('html')`.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете отключить скролл просто добавив `document.body` `overflow: hidden`. Остальные стили добавлять не надо.
[image: Пример отключения скролла]

Comment: Если бы все так просто было. Это не работает, скролл все равно происходит.

Comment: Проверьте применяются ли стили к `body` т.к. при `overflow: hidden` исчезает даже скроллбар и соотв. скролл не может происходить

Comment: Применяются. Скроллбар не исчезает.

Comment: А как вы проверяете, что стили применяются? Через инструменты разработчика? Отредактировал ответ, посмотрите